# Shock absorber change

Tags: suspension

I am owner of Mahindra Scorpio my car is riding 150000 so I want to change the shocker but I confuse only shocker change or both shocker and coil spring change pls suggest

Comment: I'd only start replacing things if there's an issue. Are the shocks leaking or showing signs of wear? Are there problems with the ride?

Answer (score 4):

Check the ride height against the original specifications and decide if the springs are weak and need replacing.

If the springs are still good then just change the shocks, but given the effort to change the shocks then you may consider doing the springs anyway. It would be annoying to change just the shocks then have the old springs fail soon after.

Comment: Bang on the money IMO.